# Concatenate variable IBOutlet inside a loop?

Tags: objective-c

I have 13 textfield  and I need to modify their values ​​according to the parameters received from an array inside a loop:

```
IBOutlet UITextField *c1_1;
....
IBOutlet UITextField *c1_13;

int xis;
int xis2;
for(xis=0;xis<14;xis++){
xis2++;
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"c1_%d.text",xis2] = lstaInfo[xis];
}
```

But the command is not working, I wish you could explain to me the possible solutions to this problem

Comment: How do you read your code with variable names like that... `O.O`

Answer (score 2):

Oh lordy. You have tons of problems.

You don't initialize xis2, but then you increment it. It may contain random garbage.

You try to assign something to a call to stringWithFormat. That is not valid Objective C. Should you flip the left and right sides of that assignment?

```
lstaInfo[xis] = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"c1_%d.text",xis2] ;
```

You also say "the command is not working" without either telling what you are trying to do, or how your code fails to accomplish that task.

You need to provide a much clearer explanation if you actually want help. (but fix the above problems first)

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the right way to do this. You want an [IBOutletCollection](http://mikezornek.com/2013/11/27/iboutletcollection/).